# How to use a function to instantiate values in an empty object

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, object

I am having trouble adding value to an empty object using a function:

I am trying to using this code to generate car objects based on random numbers that pull values from the arrays and add them to the empty object

```
var makes = ["BMW", "Audi", "Mercedez", "Range Rover", "Lexus"];
var models= ["M Series", "S Series", "AMG", "Explorer", "F Series"];
var years = [2003, 2017, 2018, 1993, 2006];
var colors = ["black", "red", "blue", "silver", "Red"];
var convertibles = [true, false];

var rand1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * makes.length);
var rand2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * models.length);
var rand3 = Math.floor(Math.random() * years.length);
var rand4 = Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length);
var rand5 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5) + 1; //using this one to determine passenger
var rand6 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2); //using this one to determine whether it's a convertible or not

function makeCar(newCar){
    newCar = {
        make: makes[rand1],
        model: models[rand2],
        year: years[rand3],
        color: colors[rand4],
        passengers: rand5,
        convertible: convertibles[rand6],
        mileage: 0
    };

    return newCar;


}

var Beamer = {};

makeCar(Beamer);

console.log(Beamer);
```

However whenever I run it in the web console of firefox i get:

```
{}
​
__proto__: {…}
```

I am using the textbook Headstart: javascript and I saw that you can create an empty object like so:

```
var lookMaNoProps = { };
```

and you can then dynamically add to said empty object like this:

```
var lookMaNoProps = { }; lookMaNoProps.age = 10;
if (lookMaNoProps.age > 5) {
lookMaNoProps.school = "Elementary";}
```

​​

Just having a little trouble trying to grasp why mine is not going through or if its a syntax error on my part.

Thanks

Comment: Note that every time you call `makeCar()` it will use the same random values. You probably want to set the variables inside the function so you get a different car each time.

Comment: Ahh I see now. Since they are created outside the function they are static, but once I put them in the function it will be as if they are being created over and over again and grab new random values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're passing an object ot your function, but then you're reassigning a new object which you return and then never use again.
You should either do:

```
function makeCar(){
    var newCar = {
        make: makes[rand1],
        model: models[rand2],
        year: years[rand3],
        color: colors[rand4],
        passengers: rand5,
        convertible: convertibles[rand6],
        mileage: 0
    };

    return newCar;


}

var Beamer = makeCar();
```

or if you want to mutate the passed object:

```
function makeCar(newCar){
    Object.assign(newCar, {
        make: makes[rand1],
        model: models[rand2],
        year: years[rand3],
        color: colors[rand4],
        passengers: rand5,
        convertible: convertibles[rand6],
        mileage: 0
    });
}

var Beamer = {};

makeCar(Beamer);
```

Comment: No idea why someone downvoted this. It's practically identical to the answer I posted 1 second later.

Comment: Thank you very much, I see now. That second one will come in handy if for changing already created objects.

Answer (score 0):

The function `makeCar(newCar)` returns a `newCar` but you are not saving it to the object `Beamer` so it stays empty.

```js
var makes = ["BMW", "Audi", "Mercedez", "Range Rover", "Lexus"];
    var models= ["M Series", "S Series", "AMG", "Explorer", "F Series"];
    var years = [2003, 2017, 2018, 1993, 2006];
    var colors = ["black", "red", "blue", "silver", "Red"];
    var convertibles = [true, false];
    
    var rand1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * makes.length);
    var rand2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * models.length);
    var rand3 = Math.floor(Math.random() * years.length);
    var rand4 = Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length);
    var rand5 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5) + 1; //using this one to determine passenger
    var rand6 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2); //using this one to determine whether it's a convertible or not
    
    function makeCar(){
        var newCar = {
            make: makes[rand1],
            model: models[rand2],
            year: years[rand3],
            color: colors[rand4],
            passengers: rand5,
            convertible: convertibles[rand6],
            mileage: 0
        };
    
        return newCar;
    
    
    }
    
    var Beamer = {};
    
    Beamer = makeCar();
    
    console.log(Beamer);
```

Comment: I'm an idiot. Thanks for pointing it out. I had been trying to pass the empty object in and have the values pushed from the function but i realized that I need to use the function to assign values to the object itself.

Comment: Glad it helped you :)